# Order by: Special characters before ABC

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, sql-order-by, special-characters

I have this sql:

```
SELECT -1 AS ID, '(None)' AS NAME
FROM TABLE_1 WHERE ID=1
UNION
SELECT ID, NAME
FROM TABLE_2
ORDER BY 2

Table data:
ID | NAME
1  | Direct
2  | Personal
3  | Etc
```

So if i execute this sql in Oracle 10 it returns these:

```
Result:
ID | NAME
1  | Direct
3  | Etc
-1 | (None)
2  | Personal
```

How is it possible to sort the "(None)" always to the top?

If i use

```
' (None) ' as Name
```

instead of

```
'(None)' as Name
```

It works, because the space before the (None), but that is not a solution.

Comment: So are you just trying to order the record with the NAME '(None)' to the top. Or is there also some relevance to making ID 1 into -1 or is that just your attempt at sorting it to the top ? I ask because if I run your query I get the 'correct' ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a dummy column `ORDER_COL` and then order on that column

```
select ID, NAME from 
(
    SELECT -1 AS ID, '(None)' AS NAME, 1 as ORDER_COL FROM TABLE_1 WHERE ID=1
    UNION
    SELECT ID, NAME, 2 as ORDER_COL FROM TABLE_2
)
order by ORDER_COL, NAME;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. `NULLS LAST` is the default for ascending order in Oracle. make it `NULLS FIRST` for  '(None)'. Also, use `UNION ALL` as `UNION` removes duplicates and is less efficient.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT -1 AS ID
        ,'(None)' AS NAME
    FROM TABLE_1
    WHERE ID = 1
       UNION ALL
    SELECT ID
        ,NAME
    FROM TABLE_2
    )
ORDER BY CASE 
        WHEN NAME = '(None)'
            THEN NULL
        ELSE NAME -- or id if you want
        END NULLS FIRST;
```